# Texture painting isn't showing up on mesh

Tags: texture-painting

I am currently trying to paint a texture on my mesh and it is not working. i brought up the UV image editor, made an image texture, selected mesh and unwrapped it. I then created a material and selected my image texture as the color. I try to go into texture paint mode to start painting but nothing happens. I have tried to flip normals being i saw someone else have the same problem and that was their answer but not for mine. Any help?

This is my .blend file: [image]

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2540" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2540/)

Comment: .Blend file provided above

Comment: @Tak I am using version 2.78

Comment: I'm using the same version and it's working fine. What OS are you?

Comment: @Tak I am OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: I'm windows 7. Looks like an OS issue. I'd raise an issue in blender bug tracker. Will update my answer accordingly as well.

Comment: Okay thanks @Tak I will be looking forward to the update

Comment: No worries, if you could accept the answer so that people with the same issue can know the reason causing this issue.

Comment: @Tak have you ever found anything out?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Tak is it my computers software do you think? Or something wrong with blender for mac in general ?

Comment: I've just tried on my mac and it's working as well, so it's not a Mac issue, it's something wrong with your system. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Oh, and i'm using Sierra by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problems painting with your file as is(just changed color) and I am on OSX El Capitan as well. I opened your file after download with 2.78a and just changed the color of the brush and started painting.[image]

Comment: Thank you guy for the help. It just started working after force quiting the app about 20 times .